# Dynamically Load HTML Based on URL

Tags: javascript, vert.x

Background: I'm writing a small web-server in Java using Vert.X. All of that works so far. Currently the web-server is basically acting as an app-server with a few GET/POST endpoints that just return or consume JSON.

I now need to add a few simple UIs to this server. In the spirit of RESTfulness I'd like to keep my URLs clean and also to return data appropriately based on the Accept: string in the request. For example, if you request from your browser `http://www.example.com/challenge/fdb123-aa12345-cbbad12-12345` it should try to load the challenge with that GUID and display an HTML form appropriately. If you do so from a commandline and indicate you accept JSON it should return JSON.

My problem is really: how do I write my HTML to extract the challenge-id and then make an ajax query back to my server to get the JSON data to fill in the form? I'm not shooting for anything fancy; the form is mostly static: a textbox, a datepicker and maybe a few other fields, that's it. Loading the JSON data from the same URL with an "accept" type of application/json should return parameters that I can use in my JS/HTML to fill in the form - my only question is, how do I make that request back to my server when I load the HTML? How do I know the challenge ID?

Comment: Templates(http://vertx.io/docs/vertx-web/java/#_templates)  are not suits for you instead ajax call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you describe is a "REST way", one endpoint supplying different outputs based on the header, but most of the frameworks don't do it like that. In frameworks like Ruby on Rails, the output is defined by the suffix: .html, .json

But let's assume that's still what we want to do:

1. If the Accept: header is JSON, return JSON
2. Otherwise, return HTML
3. In HTML, extract some URL parameter, and send it to get JSON

Ok, here we go:

```
final Vertx vertx = Vertx.vertx();

final Router router = Router.router(vertx);

router.route("/challenge/:id").produces("text/html").handler(ctx -> {
    ctx.response().sendFile("index.html");
});

router.route("/challenge/:id").produces("application/json").handler(ctx -> {
    final String id = ctx.request().getParam("id");
    final Map<String, String> res = new HashMap<>();
    res.put("challenge", id);
    ctx.response().end(Json.encode(res));
});

vertx.createHttpServer().requestHandler(router::accept).listen(8080, r -> System.out.println("Ready"));
```

And your client may look like this:

```
<script>
  $(function() {
    var path = document.location.pathname.split("/")
    var id = path[path.length - 1]
    $.ajax({
      headers: {
        // If you don't limit headers, it will send Accept: */*
        Accept: "application/json"
      },
      url: "/challenge/" + id,
      success : function(res) {
        console.log(res)
      }})
  })
</script>
```